# Backup data into another table

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I got a error like "Unknown table 'matched_temp'" when execute the following stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `apms`.`sp_partition_parkinout` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_partition_parkinout`()
BEGIN

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS MATCHED_TEMP;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MATCHED_TEMP AS
    SELECT ID FROM CARDINOUT
    WHERE (`State` = 2) AND
        (ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM CARDINOUT_MATCHED))
    LIMIT 200;

INSERT INTO CARDINOUT_MATCHED
SELECT * FROM CARDINOUT
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MATCHED_TEMP);

DELETE FROM CARDINOUT
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MATCHED_TEMP);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I want to execute it periodically to move data from cardinout into cardinout_matched. The purpose to keep table cardinout as small as possible because cardinout is queried quite often.

Is there any other option to accomplish this?

Thanks
Botem

Comment: I use MySQL Connector Net 6.2.2. Everytime I got the error like "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.". I manually executed the stored procedure, and got the error like "Unknown table 'matched_temp'".

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MATCHED_TEMP (
    ID INT
);
INSERT INTO MATCHED_TEMP
SELECT ID FROM CARDINOUT 
(...)
```

Comment: The MATCHED_TEMP should exist as there must be some records that need to be moved into matched_temp table. Anyway, I modified my code as you suggested, and I'm testing it now.